# Does low viewport fps affect rendering? (Slowed down because of many objects)

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, optimization

I have low Framerate in viewport playback. Does that affect render fps? I saw Blender rendering the animation frame-by-frame, but will my rendered video get slower because the framerate is slowed down?

Comment: Hello and welcome. No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framerate of the rendered animation can be modified in the Details Panel -> Output Properties, which is 24 by default. Now, the viewport framerate doesn't interfere with the framerate of the rendered animation. If your machine is low-end, then it will just take longer to render but that FPS won't change.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I feel less scared about experiementing with framerate